# Is there a way to export .gr2 files from Blender?

Tags: export

I need to export some models form blender to .gr2 files.
And the gr2 version should be 2.1.0.5 or 2.6

I saw there's some importer like this one:
https://github.com/Virtual-Brain/Blender_GR2_Format

But it seems like there's no exporter.
Can anyone help me?